# How to take video with Nikon D5500?

Tags: nikon, video

I cannot find the video button on Nikon D5500. How can I start recording the video?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked in the user manual?

Comment: http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/196/D5500.html

Comment: This question is off topic here. Video related questions should be asked at video.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You must be in Live View mode (activated by pulling the lever on the side of the mode dial) and press the red button (just behind the shutter).